# Kubernetes Setting Up Flannel Pod Network

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes

I'm following [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) on how to set up a kubernetes swarm.

My swarm will be as follows:

- 10.0.2.1: swarm1 (master)
- 10.0.2.2: swarm2 (worker)  (currently trying to setup a single node swarm)
- 10.0.2.3: swarm2 (worker) (not yet provisioned)

I followed it and got up to the part where I enter the command:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

And once I enter that, I get an error:

> unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": Get https://10.0.2.1:6443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.0.2.1:6443: connect: connection refused
>   unable to recognize

Which seems to mean that the kubernetes master isn't running properly.  How can I start the server so it can connect?

Answer (score 4):

This is a not enough privilege error. Either you did not run this:

`mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`

Or there is an admin.conf from previous inits. In this case while running second command and seeing  `cp: overwrite /home/aurelius/.kube/config'?`  make sure you type `yes` and press Enter.

Comment: I made sure to run those commands, and when I tried running it again I made sure to remove the entire `.kube` directory before reinitializing.

Comment: interesting, could you please try if `sudo kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml` works?

Comment: i should only install cni in master node rit??

Comment: yes, you install CNI on master node. The CNI will be a deamonset which then will make sure there is a flannel pod on each node.